# how to get Sql Exception in VIewBag.Message - asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to catch the exception message and alert the user
so when I use the exception it works but with a generic message "please see inner exception for details" What I want is display the sql exception instead for example duplicate key in my scenario I want to receive a message from a trigger.

```
try {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(investor).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (amount != 0)
        {
            InvestorPeriod ip = new InvestorPeriod();
            ip.InvestorID = investor.InvestorID;
            ip.Amount = amount;
            ip.RemainingAmount = amount;
            ip.InvestorPeriodStatusID = 1;
            db.InvestorPeriods.Add(ip);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{ 
    // I want to display the sqlexception instead of the "please see inner exception for details" and then display it a dialog

    ViewBag.Error = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: The message is telling you exactly what to do.  Do as instructed and return the `InnerException`'s message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET has a method for automatically retrieving inner exceptions (which is what you're being asked to do) - `Exception.GetBaseException()`. So you can simply change your last line to:

```
ViewBag.Error = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
```

Sometimes you do want to get all the exception messages, in which case you have to loop through the InnerExceptions (or flatten them if the exception is an AggregateException)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code how to get all inner exceptions

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{ 
    // All message will be stored here.
    var exceptionMessages = new List<string>();
    exceptionMessages.Add(ex.Message);
    while(ex.InnerException != null)
    {
         ex = ex.InnerException;
         exceptionMessages.Add(ex.Message);
    }

    // Add messages to ViewBag
    ViewBag.Error = string.Join(" ", exceptionMessages);
```

}